# React Native payout solution with Paypal and Credit card

Tags: react-native, paypal, credit-card, payout

I'm going to implement payout payment with Paypal and Credit card in my React Native application. There're two kinds of users in my app - customers and freelancers. Customers should pay to freelancers for their service.

The payment methods I'm going to implement are Paypal and various kinds of Credit cards. The backend server is based in NodeJS.

I'm quite new to this payout development and I'm really not sure where I should begin and which services I should use. Please reach out me any comments.

P.S. I'm contacting to Braintree service for several months and it's taking too long to register, so I'm looking for another solution now.

Comment: With all due respect, would've loved to see some research on your part first. This seems like on of those "homework" questions here on SO. When it comes to React Native and Paypal, a simple Google search shows that there's a library to do that: https://github.com/smarkets/react-native-paypal. As for implementing this on the backend and integrating it with a payment gateway is a complete different rabbit hole, which again can be answered with some simple research. :)

Comment: I've asked `payout` solution which `senders` are dynamic as well as `recipients`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a *native* solution that will allow you to facilitate payments to a PayPal account that is not yours.

Here is a non-native, vanilla JS demo pattern for PayPal Checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Using such a checkout, you can set a custom payee to the freelancer's account: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/